# Epic novel chronicaling the collapse of Planet Earth through pollution and other environmental catastrophies

Tags: space-colonization, mutant, apocalypse, story-identification

A novel written in the 1970's or early 80's. I read it in the late 80's. 
It starts out in 1990 where the main character(s) were stationed in Antarctica. Some Woody Allen movie is mentioned in that section.

There are several other sections, jumping ahead multiple years at a time, that describe the slow collapse of the earth through ecological apocalypse. Nature preserves are tattered from overuse. The sewers in some mega-cities are filled beyond capacity.

The severe pollution leads to severe mutations in humans and animals. The air is deadly to breathe at some point (one part takes place around Disney World, where the only remnants of humans are not only mutated but have gone completely mad.) The main character(s) and their progeny eventually flee Earth as the mutated humans etc remaining on the planet adapt to the poisonous environment through natural selection.

Does any of this sound familiar?

Answer (score 3):

This COULD be The End of the Dream, by Philip Wylie. Certainly the subject matter matches, as does the style of jumping ahead years at a time, and the timeframe for publishing. However, the ending is not the same, and humans never mutate in it. I just thought I'd mention it on the off chance you are conflating two books, something I've done many times.